# Current chatroom writing exercises and homework

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Tuesday, there's a chat session where someone poses a topic and we have 10 minutes to freewrite on it.

We're going to try making this a little more ambitious, and assign "homework" in-between the chat sessions. Answers below will contain what the exercise was and what the assigned homework was.

The main intent of these is to *get people writing*. So feel free to vary the parameters if it results in some groovy text.

Comment: Related: [Log of freewriting exercises](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/850/chatroom-writing-exercises-log)

Comment: Oh, very cool!  I look forward to reading these.

Comment: I'm glad. The few chat sessions I participated in were less active than I might have hoped.

Comment: I thought the limericks chat was a lot of fun — not just because I love limericks, but because it can take very little time to construct one. Maybe more quick poetry chats? Haikus? couplets? (Limericks also lend themselves to bawdiness, or avoidance of same, both of which can get very funny very fast.)

Answer (score 3):

30 sep 2014

**Current chat writing exercise:** 10 minute freewrite on the theme "Rescue Reward".

**Homework for next week:** Take any previous writing exercise of yours and turn it into a story. Something with a plot, characters, or (even better) both. Maybe aim for 2500 words or so, but length will be whatever it is.

**Deadline:** Have a draft before the chat session on 7 Oct 2014.

Answer (score 3):

7 Oct 2014
I'm not sure if this is a separate answer or if I'm supposed to edit Neil's answer.

**Today's current chat writing exercise**: 10 minute freewrite on the theme "the darkest days of my life".

Comment: Let's keep each week as a separate answer so we cam link to them individually.